# php regex for preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Hi im using Preg_match_all function to go through a string and return an array of its values.

```
$str = 'field1,field2,field3,field4,,,,,,,"some text, some other text",field6';

preg_match_all("~\"[^\"]++\"|[^,]++~", $str,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]);
echo "<pre>";
```

which returns this.

```
Array
(
[0] => field1
[1] => field2
[2] => field3
[3] => field4
[4] => "some text, some other text"
[5] => field6
)
```

But i also want it to return the blank ones to please help.

Comment: Might http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php be of use?

Comment: I have tried using it but it does not do what i need it to do this way i can edit each field exactly how i need it. do ya have any ideas how i could do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. str_getcsv will parse a CSV formatted string, and give you an array of the values; it will also deal with the quoted text appropriately. You can then edit the resulting array as required.

Comment: this returns the same as the above

Comment: I've just run the sample code from user729928, and it included the empty fields in the array it returned.

Comment: @andrewsi It does not appear to include the double quotes. MasterT, is that a problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, the mistake in your attempt is that you used `[^,]++`, which must match at least one character. The expression `[^,]*+` is what you want, except I think that would end up capturing empty strings after each of the matches you wanted. You could try `preg_match_all("~(\"[^\"]++\"|[^,]*+),~", $str.",",$match);` and then use `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: changed from `explode()` to `str_getcsv()` to fix enclosure issue.

I would use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for this.  It is easier to read and understand than preg_match_all(), and it will do exactly what you want it to (it even returns the empty strings).

Example:

```
<?php
$str = 'field1,field2,field3,field4,,,,,,,"some text, some other text",field6';

$results = str_getcsv($str);
print_r($results);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => field1
    [1] => field2
    [2] => field3
    [3] => field4
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => some text, some other text
    [11] => field6
)
```

Comment: Is it a problem that the array does not include the double quotes?

Comment: OMG the last time i did this i never had that output i must have put a typo some where .. thank you ..

Comment: no as long as it splits it its fine... this works for me now for some reason .

Answer (score 0):

Using `~("[^"]*"|[^,]*)(,|)~` will actually do what you need, except it will always have an empty string at the end (as that's an empty string aswell) and it adds 2 groups to the matches array.

Answer (score -2):

I think you coul also use explode.

```
my_array = explode (',', $str);
```

Be careful : "some text, some other text" will be separate in 2 cells of the array.